# Custom MastePage SharePoint 2016

Tags: custom-masterpage

I have customized masterpage from seattle.master, then using visual studio I have deployed it and applied it to the root site through feature activation. However I am not seeing my newly customized masterpage on MasterPage gallery and is not listed on ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx page on the dropdown.

**Update:**

Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Elements xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint">
  <Module Name="NewMasterPages" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" Path="NewMasterPages">
    <File Url="custom.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Url="custom.preview" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How did you deploy the master page? Please include Elements.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Module Name="NewMasterPages" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" 
           Path="NewMasterPages">
  <File Url="custom.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  <File Url="custom.preview" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
  </Module>
</Elements>

Comment: Have you published major version of the masterpage? If not then you need to do it in order to make it avalible :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [Upload and apply a new master page to a publishing site in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/stage-6-upload-and-apply-a-new-master-page-to-a-publishing-site) in order to make it to work. You can use SharePoint Designer for this to work by following the [Steps To Create Custom Master Page In SharePoint 2013 Using Visual Studio](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/).

[image]

Comment: I am not using SharePoint designer. I am working with the copy of seattle.master on visual studio itself. My solution is getting deployed and custom masterpage is being applied. But i am not seeing on the MasterPage gallery and the the dropdown you have highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew,

Can you try the following

```
  <Module Name="NewMasterPages" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" Path="NewMasterPages">
    <File Path="custom.master" Url="custom.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_masterpage_name;" />
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Custom Master Page" />
      <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="Description of the master page" />
    </File>
  </Module>
```